# php get weeklist of multitple days

Tags: php, datetime, format

I want to achieve a dynamic weeklist with daynames.

My data in an array:

```
 12.03.2018 10:00:00
 13.03.2018 10:00:00
 14.03.2018 10:00:00
 14.03.2018 13:00:00
 14.03.2018 15:00:00
 15.03.2018 10:00:00
 16.03.2018 10:00:00
```

Wished dynamic output with php:

```
 Monday
 12.03.2018 10:00:00
 Tuesday
 13.03.2018 10:00:00
 Wednesday
 14.03.2018 10:00:00
 14.03.2018 13:00:00
 14.03.2018 15:00:00
 Thursday
 15.03.2018 10:00:00
 Friday
 16.03.2018 10:00:00
```

I know that I get the day name like this:

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', '201803121830');
echo $myDateTime ->format('D');
```

How do I do this dynamically?

Comment: Where is your input data? In a file? In an array? retrieved from a database???

Comment: Its always best to show us the code you have currently!

Comment: @RiggsFolly in an array

Comment: Show us the code you are using to process the array!

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is a MySQL statement. `SELECT * FROM myDatetimeTable`

Comment: I am going to say this one more time! Show us your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the results, keep track of the current day with an outside variable, in each iteration check if the day has changed. If it did, show the name and change the outside variable. If it didn't, don't do anything:

```
<?php
$dates[] = "12.03.2018 10:00:00";
$dates[] = "13.03.2018 10:00:00";
$dates[] = "14.03.2018 10:00:00";
$dates[] = "14.03.2018 13:00:00";
$dates[] = "14.03.2018 15:00:00";
$dates[] = "15.03.2018 10:00:00";
$dates[] = "16.03.2018 10:00:00";

$day = null; // variable for keeping track
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $d = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i:s", $date);
    $dayName = $d->format("D");
    if ($day !== $dayName) { // the day changed it, update and show
        $day = $dayName;
        echo $day.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $date.PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UogAk)

*Result*

> Mon
>
> 12.03.2018 10:00:00
>
> Tue
>
> 13.03.2018 10:00:00
>
> Wed
>
> 14.03.2018 10:00:00
>
> 14.03.2018 13:00:00
>
> 14.03.2018 15:00:00
>
> Thu
>
> 15.03.2018 10:00:00
>
> Fri
>
> 16.03.2018 10:00:00